# To find/get/take one's bearings

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs

Is there any difference between these three expressions?

- *to find one's bearings*
- *to get one's bearings*
- *to take one's bearings*

Comment: There is never a difference among any expressions. There can only be a difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, **[bearings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bearing?q=bearings#bearing__7)** means

> the direction or position of something, or the direction of movement, relative to a fixed point. It is usually measured in degrees, typically with magnetic north as zero:
>
> *the Point is on a bearing of 015°*
>
> *there were no steeples or bridges from which to take a bearing*
>
> (one's bearings) awareness of one’s position relative to one’s surroundings:
>
> *he flashed the torch around, trying to get his bearings*

While there is no rigid distinction between these phrases, the connotation seems to be as follows:

> *[find one's bearings](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bearing)* - to settle into a direction or path (literally or figuratively), usually after being disoriented
>
> *[get one's bearings](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+bearings)* - again to settle into a direction, but with less suggestion of previously being lost or disoriented
>
> *take one's bearings* - to be in the process of gauging orientation or direction, also with little suggestion of disorientation; you would take your bearings before finding your bearings or getting your bearings

The distinctions are subtle at best, and the terms may often be used interchangeably with little confusion, especially the first two. *Get* seems to be the [most common form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find%20%2a%20bearings,%20get%20%2a%20bearings,%20take%20%2a%20bearings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2;,find%20%2a%20bearings;,c0;,s0;;find%20his%20bearings;,c0;;find%20their%20bearings;,c0;;find%20our%20bearings;,c0;;find%20my%20bearings;,c0;;find%20its%20bearings;,c0;;find%20the%20bearings;,c0;;find%20her%20bearings;,c0;;find%20your%20bearings;,c0;;find%20no%20bearings;,c0;;find%20new%20bearings;,c0;.t2;,get%20%2a%20bearings;,c0;,s0;;get%20his%20bearings;,c0;;get%20my%20bearings;,c0;;get%20our%20bearings;,c0;;get%20their%20bearings;,c0;;get%20her%20bearings;,c0;;get%20your%20bearings;,c0;;get%20the%20bearings;,c0;;get%20its%20bearings;,c0;;get%20some%20bearings;,c0;;get%20into%20bearings;,c0;.t2;,take%20%2a%20bearings;,c0;,s0;;take%20our%20bearings;,c0;;take%20his%20bearings;,c0;;take%20the%20bearings;,c0;;take%20their%20bearings;,c0;;take%20my%20bearings;,c0;;take%20its%20bearings;,c0;;take%20your%20bearings;,c0;;take%20compass%20bearings;,c0;;take%20some%20bearings;,c0;;take%20new%20bearings;,c0).

Comment: Is there a source?

Comment: @JohnLawler Not much. The terms seems to be interchanged quite a bit. I have added a few more links, but nothing definitive.

Comment: The definitions are OED, then? I hadn't checked.

Comment: @JohnLawler *bearings* is ODO. The others are misc. online dicts.

Comment: It is all anachronistic. You just need to learn how to enter an address or postcode in the satellite navigation device!